# How to check if a row in TABLE A matches any row in TABLE B

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I am trying to add a column in TABLE A that contains "Y" or "N" next to each row. "Y" if 3 certain columns of that row match ANY of the rows in TABLE B, "N" otherwise.

Example:

[image]

I would like to insert a column in TABLE A; in this example, it should contain "Y" next to the second entry, and "N" next to the others.

Other info: 
- Table A has around 10,000 rows
- Table B has around 20 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS(I:I,B2,J:J,D2,K:K,E2)>0
```

[image]